# When was the Cloister War, and what happened during it?

Tags: doctor-who, gallifrey

In Doctor Who series 9 the "Cloister War" was mentioned a few times (by Missy in episode 1, and the Doctor in episode 12).

When did this war happen? Was it on a big scale, and who was involved besides the Daleks, Cybermen and Weeping Angels? What were the motives to attack the cloisters on Gallifrey? And why wasn't the war focused on capturing Gallifrey itself? The cloisters are underneath the capital and hard to reach: how did the Daleks and others get there without capturing Gallifrey?

Comment: As a *Red Dwarf* fan, I'm pretty sure the Cloister War is the war fought between the two sides of the Cat race when trying to settle the most eternal of debates - red hats, or blue hats?

Comment: I'm talking about the Serie Doctor who, Dr R Dizzle

Comment: I know that, it was just a joke.

Comment: “What were the motives to attack the cloisters on Gallifrey?” How do you know the cloisters were attacked?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Dalek, Cyberman, and Weeping Angels trapped within them?

Comment: yea and attacks usually happen during a war

Comment: @randal'thor Well sure, but could they not have been captured separately? My impression was that they were subject to experiments that attempted to create hybrid beings consisting of Time Lords and their enemies.

Comment: But the time Lords don't want the Hybrid to exist because it is said that it will destroy Gallifrey. If it were experiments, why did they call it the Cloister War? I think there has been one or more wars to get into the Cloister, that's why they are trapped there.

Comment: @Slicey: “But the time Lords don't want the Hybrid to exist because it is said that it will destroy Gallifrey.” It still looks like it’s roaming around in the Cloisters though — remember the shot of the Dalek roaming around down there with the vaguely Time Lord-y screaming face?

Comment: @Slicey: “If it were experiments, why did they call it the Cloister War? ” — I don’t think they called the *experiments* the Cloister War. I just don’t think the Cloister War was a war where Time Lord enemies got into the cloisters and then got stuck there. (Like the War of the Ring didn’t have any major battles where the ring was present.)

Comment: They were supposed to be green...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the thing with the time-lordy face isn't a Dalek, it's a Cloister Wraith. The only Dalek we saw was the one begging to be killed, IIRC.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: oh, okay, right they did mention that. Was there mention of the Doctor talking to the hybrid in the cloisters when he was young? I think I need to re-watch all three parts.

Comment: no, the Cloister Wraiths talked to *him*; they told him the Hybrid Prophecy when he was little.

Comment: @randal'thor those beings were in there because they had been attempting to break in, but were trapped

Comment: @DaveJohnson But how did they get anywhere *near* one of the most protected places on Gallifrey? It could well have been part of a bigger war.

Comment: @randal'thor The Doctor explained that over the centuries weak spots would occasionally be found, and it was too tempting to not try to get in and steal the knowledge of the Time Lords.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, the Dalek etc. *did* get there during the Cloister Wars: "DALEK: Exterminate me. DOCTOR: Probably a leftover from the Cloister Wars. There's nothing we can do. Come on."

Comment: @DaveJohnson see above comment.

Comment: @randal'thor: well, even aside from the “probably”, the Dalek could have been captured elsewhere and brought there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much like the Time War in the early days of the modern series, all we know about the Cloister War are bits and pieces that have been dropped so far in dialogue. No external source has given us any other information about it, and thus, anything we might say about it is purely speculative.

Thus, the only things we really know about it is that it was apparently focused on the Matrix Cloister under the Citadel of the Time Lords (aka the Capitol), that some of its combatants wound up trapped there permanently, and that during the course of it, a young and possibly somewhat deranged Time Lord who would one day call himself "The Doctor" borrowed the moon and ran off with the President's daughter, although the Shebogans' later legends insisted it was the President's wife.

Even this much is in doubt, however, since our primary source for most of it is The Doctor himself, and he's a notorious, self-admitted, liar, and thus has to be treated as an unreliable narrator.